# Internet disconnected when I run genymotion and VM

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

When I run `genymotion` or virtual machine my internet connection shoot down.

What can I to solve this problem?

I have Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to destroy that virtual machine and to download it again? In newer versions of Genymotion I experienced many problems and this fixed it.

Comment: i have destroyed genymotion and the virtual machine and reinstall the newer version but nothing is changed : when the internet is down i must restart the laptop ....is not a IPs problem ?

Comment: Are you on some kind of student network? Maybe using proxy or vpn?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Network Adapters and Disable all adapters of Virtual box. 
After that Disable your Wifi adapter (in case you connected to wifi), 
or disable ethernet (in case you connected to ethernet), 
and Restart your WIFI and ethernet adapter.

Comment: works like a charm .. thanks .. also this should be the accepted answer